# How to merge all key values into one in single array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array value like below,

```
Array ( [0] => ["f","a","s","d"] [1] => ["d","b","a","c"] [2] => ["c"])
```

and also i want the array value like merged as below mentioned

```
Array ( [0] => ["f","a","s","d","d","b","a","c","c"])
```

The all key value should be merged under one new array key

Comment: `$merge = $arr[0] + $arr[1] + $arr[2];`

Comment: It's a hard code, may be the key loop increased

Answer (score 7):

In the PHP 5.6 release you could do this with a better approach.
PHP 5.6 added new functionality unpacking arrays called splat operater (…):

```
$arr = Array (["f","a","s","d"],["d","b","a","c"],["c"]);
$result = array_merge(...$arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass your initial array as an argument to `call_user_func_array` and use `array_merge`:

```
$arr = Array (["f","a","s","d"],["d","b","a","c"],["c"]);
print_r(call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr));
```

For php version which supports variadic arguments (since **5.6**) it is simpler:

```
print_r(array_merge(...$arr));
```

Comment: I didn't know that `array_merge` is smart to know that it's only parameter is a nested array instead of multi parameters array style . thanks for the answer, but why didn't you just call the function `array_merge($arr)` without using `call_user_func_array`

Comment: `array_merge` merges arrays. If you pass one array to it - what should it merge this array __with__?

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood.  I thought that you passed `$arr` as one parameter to `array_merge`.

Answer (score 3):

Way 1:

```
$result = array_reduce($arr, 'array_merge', array());
```

Way 2:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $arr);
```

Way 3:

```
   foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
      array_merge($result,$value);
   }
```

After getting result you have to do :
      for store as a string:

```
 $tmp[] = implode(",",$result);
  print_r($tmp);

 or as array:
 $tmp[] = result;
```

Comment: all the ways are  not working

Comment: check using print_r($result)

Comment: oh sorry i got ur point

Comment: Now my current OP: Array ( [0] => ["184","188","201","263"] [1] => ["184","188","201","263"] [2] => ["185"] [3] => ["201","202","204"] )

Comment: bu my need is Array ( [0] => ["184","188","201","263","184","188","201","263","185","201","202","204")

Answer (score 0):

you can merge the arrays using `array_merge` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php where you send in the array of arrays you have

Comment: Its not working, arrray_merge using for merge two array values

Answer (score 0):

with loop as you suggest.

```
$var = Array (["f","a","s","d"] ,["d","b","a","c"],["c"]) ;
$temp =[];
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
   foreach ($value as $key_1 => $value_1) {
      array_push($temp, $value_1);
   }
}
print_r([$temp]);
```